# How can I add different custom fields based on the product category (Taxonomy)

Tags: wordpress

As per one of my requirements I need to show only specific custom fields in the woocommerce products based on the products category So is it possible to implement the custom fields based on the product categories in the wordpress.

Comment: I think it's possible, you have to first use wp_query to check what's the category the product is under, then use a conditional statement to assign a custom field for it.

Comment: ok I will check it